# Modificar consultas hechas por el scaffolding first database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Les cuento un poco sobre mi problemática.

Por requerimientos de mi jefe tuve que hacer una aplicación mediante la tecnica first database y luego usar el scaffolding (cosa que no me gusta). Estaba acostumbrada a hacer consultas linq y llamarlas en mi controlador, ahora quiero modificar una vista donde me trae una lista con todos los registros de una tabla, pero quiero discriminar algunos, ¿En cuál archivo o clase puedo modificarla?.

Revisando el código no me queda claro si en mi controlador trae la consulta o la info de la BD. si es así ¿Cómo puedo agregar algún filtro así como un `where`?

Aquí mi controlador que estoy usando:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var usuarios = db.Usuarios.Include(u => u.UsuariosRol);
        return View(usuarios.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo determinar los datos a mostrar desde el método de acción del controlador a través de algún mecanismo de filtro, como por ejemplo el método de extensión Where. La idea es que el método de acción invoque a la vista transfiriendo únicamente los datos que se desea mostrar.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var usuarios = db.Usuarios.Include(u => u.UsuariosRol).Where(u => u.Estatus == true);
    return View(usuarios.ToList());
}
```

Comment: te marco como respuesta por que es mas clara y breve que la mia jaja

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar yo misma la problematica, la forma mas rapida de filtrar la información que me traia la consulta generada por el scaffolding fue directamente en la vista, con razor evaluando el modelo ya cargado de info.

aclaro, no les recomiendo que lo hagan ya que si bien se filtra la informacion adecuadamente, siempre vas a estar jalando todos los registros cosa que no es optima :).

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
if (item.Estatus == true)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Contador
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contrasena)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UsuariosRol.Nombre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.IdUsuario }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.IdUsuario })
    </td>
</tr>
    Contador = Contador + 1;
}
}
```

documentandome un poco mas, les dejo la forma correcta de filtar la información mediante el controlador, se realiza mediante un delegado, solo basta llamar a tu contexto de datos,luego a la tabla y llamas el metodo where junto con el campo que vas a evaluar. el include de abajo sirve para cuando se requiere hacer un inner join con otra tabla (llenar combobox por ejemplo)

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var usuarios = db.Usuarios
            .Where(u=> u.Estatus.Equals(true))
            .Include(u => u.UsuariosRol);
        return View(usuarios.ToList());
    }
```